# how to upload photo to local server using easyimage ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, image, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor for writing a text and saving it to the database, in the same time I want to upload the image to the same field in the database using easyimage plugin, its storing the image in [image]> tag in the database field